# ImageIdentify category specification

Tags: image, machine-learning, entity

There is an instance in the reference for `ImageIdentify` were a category is specified. Here it is:

```
ImageIdentify[Image, Entity["Species", "Infraspecies:CanisLupusFamiliaris"]]
```

It says `dog (species specification)`. Not knowing this instance, how would I find this command?

Even though knowing this command from the reference I have no idea how to figure it out. I tried many things and at least found `"Infraspecies"` by using `EntityClassList["Species"]`. But how do I get further to the mentioned category?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no real exact method for this. I would recommend using `Interpreter`:

```
Interpreter["Animal"]["Dog"]
```

You can also use "free form input". To do this, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> and then type "dog". If you hit enter, Mathematica will try to interpret whatever you just gave it.

Comment: Is there any good learning resource on Entity and Interpreter?

Comment: Honestly? You just have to get a feeling for what kinds of entities there are. The reason google is so useful is because you have a good idea of what kinds of results you can reasonably expect from it. You develop that from experience with it. 

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/InterpretingStrings.html